# Biblatex, refsection and ids produces unstable output. How can I correct this?

Tags: biblatex, biber

I ran across an unfamiliar error when running Biber. The error turns out to depend on the use of an old bibkey defined in `ids` rather than the new bibkey. When I switch to the new bibkey, Biber completes successfully.

Unfortunately, I've not been able to reproduce the error itself. However, I have managed to produce a different problem which I suspect is a less drastic symptom of the same underlying cause. This is a stability problem which occurs if using a key defined in `ids` within a `refsection`.

Consider the following MWE:

```
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{new-key,
  ids           =   {old-key},
  author        =   {Author, A. N.},
  title         =   {Title},
  journal       =   {Journal},
  year          =   1978,
  volume        =   3,
  number        =   2,
  pages         =   {1--43}}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\begin{document}
\textcite{old-key}
\begin{refsection}
    \textcite{old-key}
    \printbibliography
\end{refsection}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

When I run the compilation cycle `pdflatex` -> `biber` -> `pdflatex` -> `biber` -> `pdflatex` -> `biber` -> `pdflatex` -> and so on, I find that the first citation, outside the `refsection`, is stable. Once the bibkey is resolved, it stays resolved. But this is not true for the second citation inside the `refsection`. This one alternates between being resolved:

[image: correct]

and not being resolved:

[image: incorrect]

How can I avoid this problem without giving up on the extremely useful facilities of both `ids` and `refsection`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Imho this is a biblatex bug. It resets the list of key alias in `\blx@secinit`. For refsection 0 this doesn't matter as the `.bbl` is read after the command, but it destroys the list of key alias of the following refsections. Imho there is simply a `\ifcsundef` missing (like for the other commands):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\makeatletter
\def\blx@secinit{%
  \csgdef{blx@sections@\the\c@refsection}{true}% just to say we have a section for tests later
  \ifcsundef{blx@bsee@\the\c@refsection}
    {\global\cslet{blx@bsee@\the\c@refsection}\@empty}
    {}%
  \ifcsundef{blx@fsee@\the\c@refsection}
    {\global\cslet{blx@fsee@\the\c@refsection}\@empty}
    {}%
  \blx@ibidreset@force
  \blx@idemreset@force
  \blx@opcitreset@force
  \blx@loccitreset@force
  % List to track all aliases in a section. We need to output all aliases
  % to the .bcf every time so that they are visible to biber
  \ifcsundef{blx@keyaliases@\the\c@refsection} %new
    {\global\cslet{blx@keyaliases@\the\c@refsection}\@empty} %problem
    {}                                          %new
  \ifcsundef{blx@segm@\the\c@refsection @\the\c@refsegment}
    {\global\cslet{blx@segm@\the\c@refsection @\the\c@refsegment}\@empty}
    {}}
\makeatother  


\bibliography{bibkey-test}

\begin{document}

\textcite{old-key,old-key-0}


\begin{refsection}
    \textcite{old-key,old-key-1}
    \printbibliography
\end{refsection}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: Well spotted - I will add this to the next release.

Comment: For anyone looking at this in the future, this was incorporated into biblatex 3.1 which is now released.